# If $f(x)$ be a differentiable function satisfying $f(x) \, f'(-x) = f(-x) \, f'(x)$ and $f(0)=1$.Find $f(x)$.

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ be a differentiable function satisfying $f(x) \, f'(-x) = f(-x) \, f'(x)$ and   $f(0)=1$.Find $f(x)$.

There is no point guessing the function.
How should I approach this kind of sums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
f(x) f'(-x) &=& f(-x) f'(x) \\
\dfrac {f'(-x)} {f(-x)} &=& \dfrac {f'(x)} {f(x)} \\
-\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \ln f(-x) &=& \dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \ln f(x) \\
\ln f(-x) &=& -\ln f(x) + C \\
f(-x) &=& k/f(x) \\
f(x) f(-x) &=& k
\end{array}$$

Since $f(0) = 1$, we know that $k = 1$.

---

Differentiating $f(x) f(-x) = k$, we obtain $f'(x) f(-x) - f(x) f'(-x) = 0$, which is a tautology when $x=0$.

So any differentiable function on $[0,\infty)$ can be extended to a solution of the differential equation, as long as $f(0) = 1$ and $f > 0$.

Comment: But defining $f(-x)=1/f(x)$ will, in general, leave you with a function where $f'(0)$ does not exist.

Comment: If $f'(0)$ exists a priori then $f'(0)$ will exist.

Comment: I see, sorry. I read your "any differentiable function on $[0,\infty)$" as "any differentiable function on $(0,\infty)$", presuming that "differentiable" meant a two-sided derivative existed. But of course it does not mean that at $0$ on $[0,\infty)$.